# How to use clonezilla to clone disk with SELF TEST failed

Tags: 16.04, ext4, fsck, disk-management, clonezilla

In my ubuntu 16.04 system, my / partition had 11 bad sectors. I ran disk smart data and self check. It said

> Disk is OK, 11 bad sectors

To fix the bad sectors I ran I ran es2fsck. I connected the hard drive to another ubuntu system(18.04) and ran the following command on the drive with the bad sectors.

`sudo es2fsck -cfpv /dev/sda1`.

The processs took an hour with the following output [image].

Then I put the hard drive back in the original system and booted. Then I ran disk smart data and self check again. This time it gave

> SELF-TEST FAILED

**My question is can I use clonezilla to clone this partition(with SELF-test failure) to a new hard drive(ie a new partition). Or do I have to use any other tool?**

Comment: That sounds like your hard drive is failing - copy important files off _first_ (immediately...), and then yes, using Clonezilla should be OK.

Comment: @ JonasCz - Reinstate Monica : can you give some idea of using ddrescue for copying from drive to drive. I read that ddrescue can be used while running clonezilla.

Comment: I've never used ddrescue, so I can't give any useful info unfortunately.

Comment: Have you used clonezilla to copy from disk with bad sectors to new disk? Does it work?